# How do I create stacked barplots / catplots with ambigious Y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

I have grouped and aggregated data with such columns. They are populated with median values.

```
name; online_days; offline_days; hybrid_days
foo; 1; 2; 0
bar; 0.5; 2.5; 0
test; 1.5; 1.5; 0
```

I need to plot something like this

[image: Example]

I tried `sns.catplot` but it requires specific Y axis, whether I want Y axis to be `online_days`, `offline_days`, `hybrid_days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

You need to organize your data in a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), then you need to reshape this dataframe with [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) in order to have a dataframe like this:

```
name      day type  median
 foo   online_days     1.0
 bar   online_days     0.5
test   online_days     1.5
 foo  offline_days     2.0
 bar  offline_days     2.5
test  offline_days     1.5
 foo   hybrid_days     0.0
 bar   hybrid_days     0.0
test   hybrid_days     0.0
```

Finally, you can plot your data through [`seaborn.barplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

### Code

```
# import
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'test'],
                   'online_days': [1, 0.5, 1.5],
                   'offline_days': [2, 2.5, 1.5],
                   'hybrid_days': [0, 0, 0]})
df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             id_vars = 'name',
             var_name = 'day type',
             value_name = 'median')

# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(ax = ax,
            data = df,
            x = 'name',
            y = 'median',
            hue = 'day type')

plt.show()
```

### Output

[image]